# dlib labeling for object detection - detect only 60%

Tags: c++, dlib

I have question on object detection using dlib. I'm want to detect beard on face. so I'm labeling like below

[image: [image[1]]

```
typedef scan_fhog_pyramid<pyramid_down<6> > image_scanner_type; 
image_scanner_type scanner;
scanner.set_detection_window_size(80, 80); 
structural_object_detection_trainer<image_scanner_type> trainer(scanner);
```

I have trained 400 images. but detection % is 60. It is detecting even there is no beard, I think this is because I have labeled no_beard so it is detecting (may be). It seems my labeling is wrong, I just want to detect only beard face.  So in that case, do i need to  label only face that have beard? or my i should label beard and no_beard? what is going wrong? for reference i'm using [enter link description here](http://dlib.net/train_object_detector.cpp.html)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't change anything the default way of training is like this [xml](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/examples/faces/training.xml) file. Where it trains only objects as rectangular boxes (all box having nearly same width and height ratio).

It does not train any label, so I would suggest that you train only the beard images as an object. If you have enough images, It should learn the beard object.

Another idea is, detect the face by [dlib's MMOD Face detection](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/examples/dnn_mmod_face_detection_ex.cpp) and then train the beard images.

Make sure keep non-beard images without annotation, on the training so that it learns.

Comment: Yaa, my approach is to use MMOD face detection then train beard images. my question was to annotate non-beard images or not. thank you for quick suggestion. I will leave non-beard images with out annotation.

Comment: yeah, don't annotate non-beard images. eg. keep the third image in your example empty but keep it on the training set. the detector will learn the difference between them.